# Why is pandas inserting index to my to_sql even if i drop it?

Tags: pandas

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have a dataframe:

```
    ticker  year    GHG         provided
0   SECO.AB 2020    190748000   True
1   MT.NA   2020    182300000   True
2   HOLN.SW 2020    129000000   True
```

but when I try to insert into my DB I get the index as a table:

```
df[['ticker', 'year', 'GHG','provided']].to_sql('tmp_GHG', engine, if_exists='replace', method='multi')
```

I have tried:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

but it didn't make a difference and as you can see above I specified the column names to insert but it still didn't work.

Basically when I insert, in my DB I see a column called index with 0,1,2... In theory, I could drop it but I don't want it inserted there to begin with.

what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set one of the columns as index before upload.

Try

```
df= df.set_index('ticker')
```

An alternative would be hiding the index before upload.

Can also try Try

```
df.style.hide_index()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `df.to_sql(name,conn,index=False)`, and the `index=False` there will make it so it doesn't import any index.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, i think. @Lostsoul